# How to discover Sap B1 service layer address and port

Tags: sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

I am using a B1 client environment, and the support do not know the address for the service layer. Is there anywhere in the configuration where I can see server name and port so Ican user the service layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Service Layer address can be found in the System Landscape Directory (web admin) via the Services tab and the SAP Business One Service Layer Controller page.

The admin page is at https://servername:40000/ServiceLayerController/

The Service Layer itself is at https://servername:50000/b1s/v1/

Comment: What is the server name? Because all I have at my hands is a station with B1 client installed. I have DB name for connection. Th owner of this app is hard to reach out

Comment: The server name is shown in the 'Choose Company' window.

Answer (score 0):

Service layer can be installed on any machine so server name won't work always.
But if service layer is install alongside database server you can use Server property from DI Company likes this: company.Server
or if Service layer is installed alongside SAP B1 SLD: company.SLDServer

but you still need to figure out first where it is isntalled.
then you will need to replace ServerUrl with your variable.

https://ServerUrl:50000/b1s/v2